# Creating ordered multiset with correctly working find()

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to create ordered multiset with such code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

typedef long long ll;

template <class type1>
using ordered_multiset = tree <type1, null_type, less_equal <type1>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;

ordered_multiset <ll> kek;

int main()
{
    kek.insert(1); kek.insert(1);
    kek.insert(2); kek.insert(2); kek.insert(2);
    kek.insert(3);
    cout << (kek.find(2) == kek.end()) << endl;
}
```

But `find()` cant find any number because of using `less_equal < ll >` comparator instead of `less < ll >`. So, how to save dublicates in sorted set with working right `find()`?

Comment: this code does not compile for me, what is `type1`?

Comment: @rtpax Probably a missing template parameter for that `using`.

Comment: What's wrong with just using [std::multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)?

Comment: std::set, std::map, or std::multi_map are the recommended approaches in the stl. If you are really concerned about maintaining insert order, or some other arbitrary order for value entries at the same key, perhaps a `std::map<Index,std::vector<Value>>` or `std::map<Index,std::list<Value>>` would give you the behaviours you need vs. multi_map? Iterating is a slight pain, but usually turns into 2 loops instead of 1.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::multiset` lacks logarithmic `find_by_order` and `order_of_key` functions.

Comment: @rtpax sorry for mistakes, code edited

Comment: @GemTaylor i need fast inserting, erasing and finding number of elements less that some "x". And I have no idea how to replace that multiset with map. Please, explain me how to do all that functions in logarithmic time. Now I think about writing Cartesian tree, but I don't like to code such structures

Comment: Then your question is not about c++ but about your particular library. If it is a commercial or public library there may be a tag for it that will draw some more relevant experts. A 5-minute browse in google gave me no clues what your `find_by_order` and `order_of_key` functions actually should do, so I can't advise how they map onto std::map or std::set. Certainly std::map has a find() method, but I can't teach you how to transfer it all to stl. Some of your counting methods may not be trivially answered using stl.

Comment: @GemTaylor this functions included to MinGW c++ compiler libraries. `find_by_order(i)` returns iterator to set element, which would have index _**i**_ in sorted array. `order_of_key(x)` returns index, which would have _**x**_, if would be inserted into this set. In other words, returns count of elements of set, which less than _**x**_

Comment: @GemTaylor [link](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080?locale=en) here more info about this data structure

Comment: @GemTaylor the question is not only in ordered_set structure, `find()` doesn't work even in `std::set` with `less_equal` comparator. For example: [click](https://pastebin.com/Fd91dJSL)

Comment: Would that be because it needs a less-than operator, not a less-equal, as documented here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/ ?

Comment: That is far more that I am willing to digest, sorry.

Comment: @GemTaylor yes, but my task needs saving dublicates of elements, but with `less` comparator they are automatically deleted.

Comment: That is why multi_map/multi_set or map of vector. If the items with the same index are identical, then you just need a count, so map<Item,int> may be enough. If the items contain non-indexing members (payload you need to preserve) then multi_set. If the index can be separated from the payload, then multi_map; or map<vector> if you need to control the order of matching members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gnu docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/policy_data_structures_design.html)

> Brace onself: this library does not contain containers like
>   std::multimap or std::multiset. Instead, these data structures can be
>   synthesized via manipulation of the Mapped template parameter.

There is no way to use this data structure for a multiset without some boiler plate of your own. For example your might do something like the following (though this is an unsafe incomplete implementation)

```
template <class T>
class multiset_equal_list {
    friend operator<(const multiset_equal_list<T>&, const T&);
private:
    mutable std::vector<T> equals;
public:
    bool operator<(const T& arg) const { return equals[0] < arg; }
    void add_equal(const T& arg) const { equals.push_back(arg); }
}


template <class T>
class my_multiset {
private:
    std::set<multiset_equal_list<T>> values; //instead of set, you can use the __gnu_pbds tree
public:
    void insert(const T& arg) {
        auto it = values.lower_bound(arg);
        if (it == values.end() || (*it < arg)) {
            multiset_equal_list<T> to_add;
            to_add.add_equal(arg);
            values.insert(it, to_add);
        } else { //they are equal
            it->add_equal(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

The link goes more into how you might approach the problem in different ways, but you are likely better off rolling your own or using an existing library that has all the functionality you want in a more portable standard way.

Note that the reason using `std::less_equal` does not work for you is because `tree` (and `set` and `multiset` etc.) determine equivalence if the comparison evaluates false for both. eg. `a` is equivalent to `b` if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. So using `less_equal` that can never be the case (barring overloading)