# How to use policy based data structures for multiset and map?

Tags: c++, stl

Following code works for ordered_set(in which duplicates are not allowed) (CREDITS: GFG):

```
// C++ program to demonstrate the 
// ordered set in GNU C++

#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

// Header files, namespaces, 
// macros as defined above 
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp> 
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp> 
using namespace __gnu_pbds; 

#define ordered_set tree<int, null_type,less<int>, rb_tree_tag,tree_order_statistics_node_update> 

// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    // Ordered set declared with name o_set 
    ordered_set o_set; 

    // insert function to insert in 
    // ordered set same as SET STL 
    o_set.insert(5); 
    o_set.insert(1); 
    o_set.insert(2); 

    // Finding the second smallest element 
    // in the set using * because 
    //  find_by_order returns an iterator 
    cout << *(o_set.find_by_order(1))<< endl;
return 0; 
}
```

How to use the same for multiset(also for map, pair, multimap) where duplicate values are allowed.

I want to use something like:

```
#define ordered_pair tree < pair<int, int> , null_type ,  less ,  rb_tree_tag , tree_order_statistics_node_update >
```

OR

```
#define ordered_map tree < map<int, int> , null_type ,  less ,  rb_tree_tag ,  tree_order_statistics_node_update >;
```

But it throws error as:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Key, class Mapped, class Cmp_Fn, class Tag, template<class Node_CItr, class Node_Itr, class Cmp_Fn_, class _Alloc_> class Node_Update, class _Alloc> class __gnu_pbds::tree’
typedef tree < pair<int, int> ,  null_type ,  less ,  rb_tree_tag ,  tree_order_statistics_node_update > ordered_set;
```

Comment: At a guess, the `null_type` is the indicator of "set-like". For "map-like", replace it with your value type. Note the names of the template parameters in the error message

Comment: Can u please specify the exact syntax for the same along with an example. Also, the type of valid parameters that the template can accept.

Comment: Still guessing: `tree<int, int, less<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>`. The first three template parameters likely have the same constraints as those of `std::map`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51969851/2610810

Comment: Read the link. It isn't supported