# set.find() not working for ordered multiset

Tags: c++, set, ordered-tree

I am using a ordered mutliset, When I try to check if a element is present or not using st.find()
it is not giving right output.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>  
using namespace __gnu_pbds; 
using namespace std;
typedef tree<int, null_type, less_equal<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;  

int main()
{
    ordered_set st;
    for(int i = 1;i<=3;i++)st.insert(i);
    if(st.find(2)!=st.end())cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    else cout<<"NO"<<endl;
}
```

the output of the above code is NO, which is wrong

But if I change less_equal to equal in tree definition which makes it ordered set not multiset, then st.find() method is working correctly.

basically, changing

```
typedef tree<int, null_type, less_equal<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;
```

to

```
typedef tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;
```

gives "Yes" as the output but then it is not a multiset anymore.

I haven't read the docs, so I might be missing something basic.

**UPDATE** just found this link [Creating ordered multiset with correctly working find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969851/creating-ordered-multiset-with-correctly-working-find) and may be there's no direct method to use find.

Comment: You are using non-standard classes, so it's hard to answer questions about those.

Comment: Side notes: (1) [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `less_equal` is not a valid sorting condition for an ordered set, Use `less` instead.

Comment: It would have been faster to simply type in the standard `#include <iostream>` than `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, which includes every single standard header, thus risking weird behavior.  If you are not automatically and by instinct typing in `#include <iostream>` when you use `std::cout`, then there may be an issue with how you are learning C++.

Comment: Just use `std::multiset` seems like the best advice, is there any reason you are not using it?

Comment: @john Yes bcoz I wanted to access the kth element which can be done with the help of `int ele = *st.find_by_order(k);`